# ordering and selecting top

Tags: sql, sql-server

So going through W3 site to learn some SQL using NorthWind sample database.

Say if I wanted to order records by contact name and then select the top 5, what would I do?

I tried:

```
select * from customers
order by contactname 

select top 5 contactname;
```

and various permutations and getting nowhere.

thanks

Comment: @Yve: It's the SQL Server sample NorthWind database. It's been available for a decade as **the** sample DB for SQL Server, provided by Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
select top 5 * from customers order by contactname
```

if you only want the contact name specify that column in your select instead of `*`:

```
select top 5 contactname from customers order by contactname
```

Good luck on your SQL Journey!

Comment: thanks! the last one makes most sense to me but kind of goes backwards because I would have gone order then pick top 5 but this is saying pick 5 after ordered...?

Comment: Yeah sometimes SQL can seem a little backwards.  For example you specify what you are selecting before you select where you are selecting it from.  Maybe you can write a letter to the folks who came up with SQL :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 5 contactName,* from table order by contactname
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've got is close, just a little tweaking:

```
SELECT TOP 5 customers.contactname
FROM customers
ORDER BY customers.contactname
```